# Isometry between $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ and $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, isometry

Let
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix},
C =
\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 \\
0 & -i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
be a basis of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.
Also define $g_\lambda$, for $\lambda > 0$, to be the Riemannian metric on the Lie group $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ such that $(A, B, \lambda C)$ is an orthonormal basis.
I want to show that the well known diffeomorphism
$$
(z,w)\in\mathbb{S}^3 \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
z & w \\
-\bar w & \bar z
\end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{SU}(2)
$$
is an isometry when $\lambda=1$ and $\mathbb{S}^3$ is equipped with its standard round metric.

I tried to use charts on both sides but it's too much calculus and doesn't seem to go somewhere.

Comment: Charts are usually the way to go with these types of questions

Comment: When $\lambda=1$, $g_\lambda$ reduces to $g_\lambda(X)=\frac12 X^* X$, this should make it easier to check.

Comment: Edit: $g_1(X,Y)=\frac12 \text{tr}(X^*Y)$

Comment: $A, B, C$ induce a local orthonormal chart on $SU(2)$. Use the map to pull that chart back to $S^3$. Show that the chart is orthonomal there. The exercise is totally algebraic.